# Netbeans autocomplete, search and other functionalities not working

Tags: netbeans, netbeans-8

I am using Netbeans 8.2 in Ubuntu 16.04. Whenever I checkout a branch using git, the search, goto function definition and the universal search(ctrl+shift+f) etc breaks. But it works when I delete the project from Netbeans and add it again. But this method won't retain the last opened tabs. Could somebody please suggest me a fix?